# Is it possible to change a pair that is in a map?

Tags: c++, stdmap

So i was testing some stuff with maps and pairs and i got into a problem.

```
    std::map<std::string, int> pairTest;

pairTest.insert(std::make_pair("Peter", 100));

for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = pairTest.begin(); it != pairTest.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

How can i change "Peter" to Daniel? 
Am i supposed to be able to do that?

How can i make pairs never be changable and add the same key with different value?

I have tried another way, is this a more correct way of doing it?

```
    std::map<std::string, int> pairTest;

pairTest.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("Peter", 100));

for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = pairTest.begin(); it != pairTest.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Use a [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) if you need several values for the same key.

Comment: `pairTest["Peter"] = 100;` inserts if there is no `"Peter"` in the `map` already, otherwise updates the value of the existing entry.

Comment: Use `std::multiset<std::pair<std::string,int>>`  if you want to store two Peters that have the same age :)

Comment: @Acorn i didnt knew what multimap was at that time! I understand it now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, How can i change "Peter" to Daniel?

You cannot. Your best option is to remove "Peter" and then to add "Daniel".

The reason you cannot change the `first` of the `pair`, which is the `key` of the item, is that it is expected to be a constant from a conceptual point of view. The standard library enforces it by defining `std::map<K, V>::value_type` to be `std::pair<const K, V>`. If you are able to change the value of the `first`, you will destroy the sorting order of the items in the map.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: You will destroy even more; I spent weeks with that error: changing the key changes the hash of it, and then any reorg of the map's internal tree will result in undefined behavior and very 'funny' issues...

Comment: I used a pointer to a class as key, and defined a custom hash that works on the class instance, not on the pointer. The idea was to recognize newly created but internally identical objects as already being in the map. Through the pointer I can of course modify the object (as it doesn't modify the pointer). Don't try it though, as I said, it gets nasty.

Comment: The right solution is to ensure that _the hash stays unchanged_ if you do changes to the object.